# row_nums without using row_number function?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
    *, (SELECT count(1) from color i WHERE i.NAME <= c.NAME)
FROM color c
ORDER BY name
```

Output:

```
id          NAME                      
----------- ------------------------- -----------
4           blue                      1
1           orange                    2
3           red                       3
2           yellow                    4
```

I didn't understand how this query generates row_nums without using row_number function?
How the query flow would be when subquery will be executed before order by or after?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a correlated subquery. For each row in `c`, count the number of rows in the same table, with the same name or a lower name.

This is an absolutely inefficient and wasteful way to generate a row number, but is likely the most common way people worked around the lack of such a function in, say, SQL Server 2000. Today, of course, you should be using:

```
SELECT id, name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)
  FROM dbo.color
  ORDER BY name;
```

Assuming `name` is unique and you don't need to break ties.

Comment: How would i break ties?

Comment: @RegisteredUser - however you wish :)  Adding an id to the ORDER BY clause is a common method.

Comment: @RegisteredUser It depends on what you mean, since ties can come in many varieties. If name is not unique, then you can choose another column to order by *after* name, for example `OVER (ORDER BY name, id)` would give `4,blue` a row number of 1, and `6,blue` a row number of 2.

Answer (score 2):

the subselect

```
select count(1) from color i where i.name <= c.name)
```

counts the rows where the name is smaller or equal to the name in the current row of the outer select, thus counting the rows up to that point. you can confuse it by having a colour twice in that table. try inserting red again and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

It's using a correlated subquery to count the number of rows above it.  Note that for large datasets, this query will be vastly less performant than using ROW_NUMBER(), which uses fixpoint logic to determine its place instead of running COUNT for each row.

Comment: FYI: "Performant" is a noun - someone who performs something capably.

Comment: @swasheck: This doesn't appear to be the general understanding - http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/performant

Comment: Why not just use a word that conveys the same meaning (like `efficient`) without any of the controversy (or causing people to bang their head on their desk)? This is like using utilize instead of use, or myriad instead of many, except that performant is still not in the dictionary. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38945/what-is-wrong-with-the-word-performant The key is, when you choose to use that word, which many people believe is not a word, they may think less of you. Here, who cares; in a business environment, use caution. IMHO.

Comment: @PinnyM that's the link i looked at too which notes that it's a noun. "performant" isn't in the dictionary at all.

Comment: @swasheck - it also lists it as an adjective (actually before it lists it as a nount).

Comment: Just because something is listed in wiktionary or urban dictionary doesn't make it a word - they're just documenting the way people use a non-word.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I wasn't aware that anyone hadn't heard this word used as an adjective (or that someone who hadn't heard it would therefore assume that it is incorrect).

Comment: @swasheck - is Oxford Dictionary an acceptable resource? http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/translate/french-english/performant

Comment: @PinnyM your statement makes it sound like it is correct. Can you please point me to Mirriam-Webster's or Oxford's definition of performant? People who try to look the word up don't have to *assume* it's incorrect.

Comment: OMG. That's how a French person would say a French word in English. There is no translation because ***it's not an English word***. Notice that *the only* reference of that "word" in Oxford is in the translation section. Find a definition.

Comment: Oxford actually doesn't have an entry for performant at all in English (noun _or_ adjective).  However, it is heavily used in the US (especially in the IT field).  Not sure why that is...  `efficient` it will be from here on in...

Comment: @PinnyM because people keep using it. Same reason [ginormous became a word](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/ginormous?q=ginormous). Doesn't make it sound any better just because it's used more often than it should be. Anyway, use whatever "words" you want, just prepare to defend yourself every time you use a non-word with people who rely on rules, the dictionary, etc. and not how Shon the server guy talks.

Comment: Hey now @AaronBertrand lets not knock ginormous.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - note that Oxford does have an entry for ginormous :)  And at least 'performant' is acceptable in French for quite some time (and likely has the same root as the English 'performance').

Comment: I know, I included a link to it. My point was that just because a word is popular (and Oxford eventually succumbs to including it in the language), does not magically make it sound not dumb. To some people, words will never be considered by them to be real words. I'm not going to suddenly start using performant when Oxford does include it (and I assume they eventually will), because it will still sound dumb to me, and I know it will still sound dumb to the people I interact with daily.

Comment: I now need a new desk from all the times I've had to bash my head from these comments.